Getting the error 'ReferenceError: primordials is not defined' when creating a React Project
When I'm creating a new React project, it does not create and giving a error. I will mention the error below.
C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_2.0>npx create-react-app lms-2.0

Creating a new React app in C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_2.0\lms-2.0.

evalmachine.<anonymous>:42
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:42:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)

Node.js v18.12.0
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

evalmachine.<anonymous>:42
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:42:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)

Node.js v18.12.0

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting lms-2.0/ from C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_2.0
Done.

"create-react-app lms-2.0" is the given command to create the project. But it gives the error 'ReferenceError: primordials is not defined' without creating the project

Are you familiar with Docker? I wonder if you'll have an easier time of it if you use a Linux container on Windows.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Usually, such errors mean that the node version you are trying to use is incompatible with the package you are trying to install. Try downgrading node.js version to 16. And if that works, search for manual package upgrades that cause error in v18

Isn't 16 and 18 now so old that upgrading to 20 is the preferred course of action?

Well, of course. Question is at what lowest point it is being assembled. And then see how to bring up the library that causes issues to an up to date node version.
